# how do we load particular class dynamically using dependency injection in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

how do we load particular class dynamically using dependency injection in spring?

Comment: Tom is right, however you should check Spring Documentation first (https://spring.io/docs). It is absolutely one of the best I have ever seen. Always try to find your answer there first and then ask on SO :)

Comment: Please do not deface your question like this. I am rolling it back.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `@Bean` with names like:

```
@Bean(name={"airtel"})
 public Operator getOperator1() {  
  return new Airtel();
 }

@Bean(name={"idea"})
 public Operator getOperator2() {  
  return new Idea();
 }
```

and Autowire them with `@Qualifier`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("airtel")
private Operator airtel;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("idea")
private Operator idea;
```

Answer (score 1):

While Tom Sebastian's answer is correct it can be improved (I ran out of space in the comment block to explain the improvements).

The convention when using `@Bean` is to omit "get" from the method name. This is because [configuration classes use a method's name as the bean name](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming). In your `@Configuration`-annotated class declare the beans like this:

```
@Bean
public Operator airtel()
{
  return new Airtel();
}

@Bean
public Operator idea() 
{
  return new Idea();
}
```

To inject your beans use `@Resource` rather than `@Autowired` as recommended in the [Spring reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use `@Autowired`, even if is technically capable of
>   referring to a bean name through `@Qualifier` values. Instead, use the
>   JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation...

```
@Resource(name="airtel")
private Operator airtel;

@Resource(name="idea")
private Operator idea;
```

As it turns out the `name` of the `@Resource` isn't required here...I included it above to demonstrate how it's used.  If the name of the field is the same as the name of the bean (which in this example is the method name in the `@Configuration`-annotated class) then `name` is not required:

```
@Resource
private Operator airtel;

@Resource
private Operator idea;
```

As I said, Tom's answer is correct; I wanted to expand it a little with slightly more advanced details.